# output of the json not formatted in APIM developer portal

Tags: json, azure-api-management

output of the json not formatted in APIM developer portal and HTTP response gives as follows also

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK

> api-supported-versions: 1.0,2.0
> content-length: 1979
> content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> date: Tue, 06 Sep 2022 11:50:38 GMT
> strict-transport-security: max-age=15552001; includeSubDomains; preload

in above it say content-type: application/json but out put as below (in the developer portal responses section content type also "application/json" )

```json
{
  "totalRowCount": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "Code": "",
      "prCode": "CW1208",
      "Name": "CW1208 Quarterly Milestones",
      "description": "",
      "CategoryCode": "Efficiency",
      "dataSource": "",
      "custodian": "",
      "TimeframeCode": "Lag",
      "TypeName": "Single",
      "active": true,
      "InputTypeCode": "Input",
      "rOfficer": "Stephen MCKAY",
      "rOfficerCode": "Stephen ",
      "AggregationMethodCode": "Average",
      "reportingPeriod": "Quarter(s)",
      "responsibleOfficer": "Stephen ",
      "unit": "%",
      "method": "MOREISBETTER",
      "datefrom": "2021-04-01T00:00:00",
      "dateto": "2021-06-30T00:00:00",
      "target": 100.00,
      "actual": 0.00,
      "variance": 0.00,
      "performance": 0.000000,
      "trafficLight": "OFFTRACK",
      "comment": "Quarterly comment.."
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

This is how I added the response
[image]

in the developer portal example output [image]

all operation policies

```
        <set-header name="Token" exists-action="skip">
            <value>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.GetValueOrDefault("Token"))</value>
        </set-header>
        <choose>
            <!--QA-->
            <when condition="@(context.Subscription.PrimaryKey.Equals("8ug4ac4a02"))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://xxxxx.com/API/api/v1/" />
            </when>
            <!--Other Clients-->
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://xxxxemo.xxxx.com/api/v1/" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <set-header name="X-Powered-By" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="X-AspNet-Version" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-body template="none"></set-body>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 404)">
                <set-status code="200" reason="No Records Found" />
                <set-body template="none">{"totalRowCount":0,"data":[{"":""}]}</set-body>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: How to you create the response body? Are you able to share code?

Comment: OK, this is part of the definition. But this is not the code which is executed. Do you have defined policies? Are you forwarding the request to a backend service which delivers the json?

Comment: currently i didn't don't have any backed police but i put some outbound( checking StatusCode == 404  ) and  inbound(using set-backend-service to redirect  )

Comment: so, how do produce the output? Using the Mock-Policy?

Comment: no i didn't us any policy just what i did was import the swagger json the via Create from OpenAPI specification and match the URls.. last few month it worked and now it  end points getting the unformatted json output

Comment: so you just have a display issue in Azure Portal? Not in the real response and also not in the Developer Portal?

Comment: issue display in the Developer Portal.. i will update the question now

Comment: The question shows only a screenshot from Azure Portal. Can you please post also a screenshot from the Developer Portal?

Comment: This is the developer portal and it looks fine: https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.developer.azure-api.net/api-details#api=abc&operation=get-milestones

Comment: did update the question also

Comment: OK, so you are able to execute the operation. Are you able to share the code of this operation? The policy...

Comment: updated the question again by adding all operation policies

Comment: It's not clear to me how you produce the output in the screenshot. Based on your policy, the body is set to empty: `<set-body template="none"></set-body>`

Comment: I think this is the issue the latest APIM Devportal release has made, as we haven't changed APIs behing, but we got same missformatted HTTP responses. I raised the issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/1936)

Answer (score 1):

Please set the [response content type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader) to `application/json`.

Outbound policy:

```
<outbound>
    <set-header name="X-Powered-By" exists-action="delete" />
    <set-header name="X-AspNet-Version" exists-action="delete" />
    <set-body template="none"></set-body>
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 404)">
            <set-status code="200" reason="No Records Found" />
<!--
            <set-body template="none">{"totalRowCount":0,"data":[{"":""}]}</set-body>
-->
            <set-body>@{
                  var body = new JObject();
                  body["totalRowCount"] = 0;

                  var data = new JArray();
                  var dataValue = new JObject();
                  dataValue[""] = "";
                  data.Add(dataValue);

                  body["data"] = data;
                  return body.ToString();
            }</set-body>
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
        </when>
    </choose>
    <base />
</outbound>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: getting same result still json in not formatted in the developer portal

Comment: I changed the body. You can try it here: https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.developer.azure-api.net/api-details#api=abc&operation=get-milestones

Comment: The problem, that you are faking your response via policy, therefore it could be differently represented in Devportal.